# How to create a batch file which runs multiple maven, CMD, and node commands?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, batch-file, spring-boot

I have a use case where I need to deliver an application to a client as a one-click executable so that he doesn't have to perform multiple operations to setup and run the application.

Obviously, I can host it using hiroku or any other hosting service but I'm running short on time.

My application consists of - Angular5 frontend + Spring boot middleware + MongoDB backend

The repository is on github. Also, I have separate backend and frontend. So the sequence of commands in bat file are:

1. git clone - my repository.git
2. cd backend-app > mvn spring-boot:run
3. cd.. > cd frontend-app > npm install > npm build(or start)
4. Open browser.

Here is what I came up with:

```
echo off

call git clone https://github.com/saranshbansal/xyz.git

cd angular-frontend
call npm install && npm build

cd..
cd spring-boot-backend
call mvn spring-boot:run

cmd explorer "http://localhost:4200/"
```

However, this bat file only executes the first command and exits. It doesn't execute rest of the commands. I've tried changing the order but the result is same.

Please help in fixing it.

Comment: Did you try without `call` ?

Comment: I would say it is stopping after `npm build`.  `NPM` is a batch file so you need to use `call npm install && CALL npm build`

Comment: @Squashman ah good catch! I'll try that. However, control never returns even after calling the maven command. So it will still fail to call the last command -> cmd explorer "http:/...."

Comment: @SachaDee hmm let me chk and revert back.

Comment: I assume Maven has to stay running for you to be able to access it with a web browser.  Batch files are single threaded scripts.  The process you are calling has to start and finish before it can move onto the next task.  So I am assuming you need to start maven in a separate process. `start "" mvn spring-boot:run`